# MYSQL - Using CURDATE() in a WHERE BETWEEN returns NULL

Tags: mysql, date, null, where-clause, between

Trying to use CURDATE() to filter for last 30 days but it is just returning a NULL row.

Query:

```
SELECT

vcrs.vcrDate AS DATE,
vcrs.jobNumber AS RO_NUM,
vhcrows.description AS DESC,
vhcrows.partNumber AS PART_NUM,
vhcrows.unitPrice AS UNIT_PRICE,
vhcrows.partQuantity AS QUANTITY,

FROM vhcrows 
INNER JOIN vcrs ON vhcrows.vcr_id = vcrs.uid
INNER JOIN usergroup_manufacturers ON usergroup_manufacturers.usergroup_id = usergroups.uid

WHERE usergroup_manufacturers.manufacturer_id = 7
AND vcrs.vcrDate BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE()),'%Y%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y%m%d')
AND vcrs.vcrStatus <> '-1'
AND vcrs.vcrSubStatus = 4
AND vhcrows.rowType IN (1,2);
```

It should be returning something like this:

```
DATE        RO_NUM   DESC                   UNIT_PRICE  QUANTITY
20140805    36815    BALL JOINT             24.85       1
20140821    11763    BALL JOINT             31.4        1
20140806    12076    BOLT                   4.44        2
20140806    12076    BOLT                   4.44        2
20140828    37994    DEF WIPER              9.53        3
20140804    11536    DRIVE MEMBER           106.42      1
20140804    11536    DRIVESHAFT             280.78      1
20140805    36815    NUT                    1.33        1
20140813    56817    RADIO WITH CD PLAYER   1399.88     1
20140820    203102   REF.                   16.7        1
20140801    11517    TENSIONER              64.01       1
20140814    12203    WHEEL BEARING          162.13      1
20140807    51520    WIPER                  9.53        3
20140821    198081   "RANGE"                22.77       1
```

But, as I said, I am just getting NULL.

Thanks!

*** vcrs.vcrDate is stored as e.g. 20140911 ***

Comment: have you seen what (CURDATE()),'%Y%m%d') returns or if it is null?

Comment: SELECT
DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE()),'%Y%m%d');

returns 20140911

Comment: What is `curDate` formatted as?  It should be a date.

Comment: dates in the database are in YYYYMMDD format so I used DATE_FORMAT to match CURDATE() to the database format. Otherwise it returns YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: What happens if you test this with a manually entered date range IE BETWEEN '20140911' AND '20140811'? - If it gets that wrong too try adding in "-" IE BETWEEN '2014-09-11' AND '2014-08-11'(you may have to format vcrDate the same way)

Comment: It has been working with a manual date range in the format YYYYMMDD, trying to improve on that with CURDATE() which is where I have hit a bit of a wall...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting `CURDATE()` to a string?  Just do:

```
vcrs.vcrDate BETWEEN CURDATE()) AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

This assumes that `vcrDate` is stored in a native date format.  If not, edit your question and explain how it is stored.

If `vcrs.vcrDate` is actually an integer, then you want your `CURDATE()` to be an integer.  You can take the same path you have, but do the final convert to an integer:

```
vcrs.vcrDate BETWEEN cast(DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE()),'%Y%m%d') as unsigned) AND
                     cast(DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y%m%d') as unsigned)
```

Comment: Gordon - the date format is yyyymmdd - it is in the example output.

Comment: question edited, tried your suggestion with cast() as unsigned, still returning NULL

Comment: @Giles . . . What is the type of the column?

Comment: I assume char or (less likely) int - I would not think it was date as a simple select would return the date type with "-" separators.

Comment: MySQL has very interesting rules for converting dates to strings and ints.  You really should be storing the value as a native date/time format.  Because you are not, I would recommend very explicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to reformat vcrs.vcrDate rather than CURDATE():

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(vcrs.vcrDate,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN SUBDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Thank you Giles and Gordon Linoff for your help!